# "Extract Variable" in Visual Studio without ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, refactoring, code-snippets

I don't have ReSharper at my current gig, and I miss the "Extract Variable" refactoring. I understand that it's possible to write your own refactoring "snippet" in VS. Does anybody have one that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://www.davesexton.com/blog/post/Custom-C_2300_-Code-Snippets.aspx), but it does not seem to be a documented feature:

> **Snippets For Refactoring**
>
> Browse to your "*Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\Snippets\language id\Refactoring*" directory and you'll find the snippets used to perform the refactoring techniques in the *Refactor* menu. (...) If you're going to try modifying these snippets then (...)

Another way would be a write a macro using the EnvDTE programming model. Not easy, but should be feasible.

Comment: I can't find the snippet for extracting a variable. Could you name it in your answer?

Comment: The original question, as I understood it, is "how to create snippets". These files are in a directory called Refactoring, but they seem to let us add a piece of code, rather than change existing code. At the time of the question, I guess the only complete answer is to write a macro. As of today, your answer is better.

Answer (score 20):

In Visual Studio 2017, if you select something, on right-click you will find a menu option "Quick Actions and Refactorings", with shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.
This seems to be somewhat similar to ReSharper's <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This allows you to extract a variable, as in this example where the text was selected and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> was pressed:
[image: extracting a constant]

Comment: Is this VS2017 Enterprise? I don't see this option in the Professional version

Comment: works in my VS2017 Enterprise, although it takes ~1min to calculate it... a bit shameful, as for resharper it's 1s in the same project

Comment: @Kentative Professional. But you must select the text that you want to extract a variable from.

Comment: works for VS2017 Professional as well. Why `Ctrl+.` though and not `Alt+Enter`...? `Alt+Enter` is already used on VS2017 for fix suggestions.